How to Obfuscate a .NET 8 VB Forms App as a Single File When Only the DLL is Recognized as .NET?
The Issue

When I build my VB Forms application in Visual Studio (targeting .NET 8), it generates both an .exe and a .dll.
The obfuscation tool I’m using (such as ConfuserEx or ArmDot) does not recognize the .exe as a valid .NET assembly and throws an error indicating that it "doesn't appear to be a .NET assembly."
The .dll generated alongside the .exe is recognized as a .NET assembly, and I can successfully obfuscate it.

What I Want to Achieve
I would like to deploy the application as a single, obfuscated .exe file without any external DLLs.
What I've Tried

Single-file publish:

I tried using the Publish feature in Visual Studio to produce a single file by going to Project Properties > Publish > Publish Options and selecting the "Produce single file" option.
However, this creates a single .exe file, but since the obfuscation tool doesn’t recognize it as a .NET assembly, I can’t obfuscate the final published output.


Replacing DLL with Obfuscated Version:

I also attempted to obfuscate just the DLL (since the obfuscator recognizes it as a .NET assembly) and then replace it in the output directory before publishing.
Unfortunately, this approach doesn’t work because the publishing process rebuilds everything, effectively overwriting my obfuscated DLL with the original one.



My Question
Is there a way to:

Obfuscate a .NET 8 Windows Forms application so that it can still be published as a single .exe file?
Ensure that the obfuscation tool recognizes and obfuscates the .exe or allows me to embed the obfuscated DLL into the final single-file executable?

Alternatively, if there's another approach to obfuscating a .NET 8 VB application that can achieve a single-file output, I would be open to trying that.

It sounds like you're targeting .NET 5+ but your obfuscation tools only support .NET Framework 4.x.. (and FWIW, speaking as someone who dabbles in part-time software reverse-engineering, I'll tell you that obfuscation tools are a complete waste of money. May I ask what your threat-model is that led you to believing you need to obfuscate your IL?

Try Obfuscar

The author of ArmDot is here.

The obfuscation tool I’m using (such as ConfuserEx or ArmDot) does not recognize the .exe as a valid .NET assembly and throws an error indicating that it "doesn't appear to be a .NET assembly."

This is expected because the .exe is simply a launcher that loads the corresponding .dll, which is the actual .NET assembly. This setup is common in modern .NET applications.
You should obfuscate the .dll, not the .exe.

Obfuscate a .NET 8 Windows Forms application so that it can still be published as a single .exe file?

You'll need to integrate obfuscation into the build process. Add the following to your .csproj file:
<Target Name="Protect" AfterTargets="AfterCompile" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Assemblies Include="$(ProjectDir)$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ArmDot.Engine.MSBuildTasks.ObfuscateTask
    Inputs="@(Assemblies)"
    ReferencePaths="@(_ResolveAssemblyReferenceResolvedFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)')"
    SkipAlreadyObfuscatedAssemblies="true"
    />
</Target>

This setup will run ArmDot before publishing, ensuring your assemblies are obfuscated.
